# setting a foreign key to an empty string

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, insert

I'm trying to set a foreign key to an empty string but i keep getting this error.

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails `` (`msis230`.`deptchair`, CONSTRAINT `deptchair_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PROFESSORID`) REFERENCES `professor` (`PROFID`)) ``

this is my code:

```
INSERT INTO DEPTCHAIR (PROFESSORID, DEPTID)
VALUES ('SJ001', 'MSIS');
INSERT INTO DEPTCHAIR (PROFESSORID, DEPTID)
VALUES ('', 'BIO');
INSERT INTO DEPTCHAIR 
VALUES ('JS001', 'PHY');
INSERT INTO DEPTCHAIR 
VALUES  ('NS001', 'MKT');
INSERT INTO DEPTCHAIR 
VALUES ('', 'ECO');
```

Comment: Do you have a record in the professor table with a blank for PROFID?

Comment: @MikePetri I have set PROFID as a not null primary key.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches you can take

### APPROACH #1 : Add to professor table

```
INSERT INTO professor (PROFID) VALUES ('');
```

Then, all INSERTs to `DEPTCHAIR` will work.

### APPROACH #2 : Disable Foreign Key Check

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
INSERT INTO DEPTCHAIR (PROFESSORID, DEPTID)
VALUES ('', 'BIO');
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Even '' is a value that has to exist in the parent table.

If you don't want to add that to your professor table use `NULL` instead like Akina already said in the comments

```
INSERT INTO DEPTCHAIR (PROFESSORID, DEPTID)
VALUES ('SJ001', 'MSIS');
INSERT INTO DEPTCHAIR (PROFESSORID, DEPTID)
VALUES (NULL, 'BIO');
INSERT INTO DEPTCHAIR 
VALUES ('JS001', 'PHY');
INSERT INTO DEPTCHAIR 
VALUES  ('NS001', 'MKT');
INSERT INTO DEPTCHAIR 
VALUES (NULL, 'ECO');
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to set a foreign key to an empty string

An empty string is *still* a string and, therefore, a valid value that *will* be looked up in the referenced table.

To "get rid" of the field, you ***must*** set it to NULL.

> INSERT INTO DEPTCHAIR (PROFESSORID, DEPTID) VALUES ( '', 'BIO' );

Assuming you could create this row, *what* would it *represent*?

If you want to denote that this department *has* no chair, then the row should not exist *at all*.
A Left Join query between Department and this table would show those departments without chairs.

```
select * 
from department 
order by 1 ; 
+------+
| dept | 
+------+
| BIO  |
| ECO  |
| MKT  |
| MSIS | 
| PHY  |
+------+

select * 
from deptchair 
order by 1, 2 ; 
+------+-------+
| dept | chair | 
+------+-------+
| MKT  | NS001 | 
| MSIS | SJ001 | 
| PHY  | JS001 |
+------+-------+

select 
  d.code 
from department d
left join deptchair dc 
     on   d.dept = dc.dept 
where dc.chair is null 
order by 1 ;
+------+
| dept | 
+------+
| BIO  |
| ECO  |
+------+
```